# Elliptical marquee tool selecting as rectangles?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I changed my marquee selection to elliptical, and when I click and drag a circle/elliptical appears. When I release for the desired collection, the selection changes from the elliptical to a cross section of rectangles instead. Is this a setting I accidentally pressed, or something I can reset back to an elliptical?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you down at pixel-peeping resolutions? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD8qp.png

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE Can you take a screen capture showing the problem and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/153795/edit) and share the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you clicked on one of those buttons or your alt or shift key is stuck.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really cover for the elliptical marquee.

Comment: same options are available for both rectangular and ellipse selection tools...

Comment: Indeed they are… which still doesn't explain the OP's *"selection changes from the elliptical to a cross section of rectangles instead"*

Comment: @Tetsujin sure does. If you add to a previous selection of boxes but select inside them.

Comment: @Tetsujin well technically you are right 'cross section' as far as I know refers to a 2d shape you get when cutting straight through an 3d object. I don't see how thats possible in a 2d software – so I assumed it is more likely that it was not explained quite right.

Comment: I'm assuming the term was mis-chosen & should probably have been 'selection' rather than 'cross section', but that's why I posted a comment with an illustration & asked for some clarification.